# Why did notable mathematician Walter Rudin have so few citations according to ResearchGate?

Tags: publications, citations, mathematics

According to ResearchGate, Rudin had about 30 ish papers and 500 ish citations.

How come so few?  I thought he was this legend of maths.

Here's his profile:

https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/21400404_Walter_Rudin

Comment: The book by W. Rudin "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" has 10304 citations. Please use [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=rudin+principle+of+analysis&btnG=) yourself.

Comment: I haven't really worked in analysis where Rudin made his contributions but writing a very popular text book and making big research contributions are separate things. For a more drastic example consider the Stewart calculus books. This is probably the most sold and best known maths book in the world but that doesn't make Stewart a notable mathematician research wise.

Comment: It tells much about the quality and credibility of ResearchGate.

Comment: Nearly every mathematician in my, now very old, generation studied from one or more of his books. I still have some of them on my shelf.

Comment: @scaaahu In terms of numbers, these comparisons are highly misleading. A Google Scholar citation is not the same thing as a Researchgate citation, which is not the same thing as a Scopus citation.

Comment: MathSciNet lists 11977 citations for Rudin.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni so all citations are (not) equal, but some are more equal than others...

Comment: MathSciNet also shows something like 150 research papers by Walter Rudin.  Clearly Researchgate's database is very incomplete.  I suspect they don't do so well with papers from before the Internet era.

Comment: I  don't know how many times I've mentioned, in the "background" section of a paper, Walter Rudin's 1956 theorem that the continuum hypothesis implies the existence of P-point ultrafilters. Almost none of those mentions included a citation, because this fact has become so familiar. I suspect that the same thing has happened to other results of his.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will be a bit orthogonal to the question. But Rudin's place is due to more than the number of papers written and citations.

According to the [Math Genealogy project](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=8419), Rudin produced 24 successful PhD students and has 125 "descendants". These numbers are pretty big. Some of his students were, themselves very productive.

A professor can be a collaborator, but not an author on a pretty large number of papers, and this is pretty typical in math.

Note also, that in mathematics it was then not normal for a professor to be listed as co-author on their student's work. I think that is still pretty standard, actually.

So, the number of citations isn't necessarily the only measure of influence.

---

But as to the question itself, mathematicians have moved on to other, newer, areas since his time. In some sense this is, or can be, due to success in solving outstanding problems, leaving only the hardest questions still open. So people work in areas in which it might be a bit easier to be "productive".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what ResearchGate is doing, but Google Scholar shows many many more citations: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C6&q=walter+rudin&btnG=

For example, "Principles of mathematical analysis" has more than 10,000 citations. "Real and complex analysis" has more than 16,600. "Fourier analysis on groups" has 3,500. These are all exceedingly large numbers for mathematicians.